# sata drive not updating to current kernel. nvme drive has 3 choices for kernel

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, kernel

my computer has a sata drive sda that it boots from but the system runs on a nvme drive which is selected by the grub on the sata.
the nvme is regularly updated and I watch the logwatch files for any kernel updates then boot from the sata and run apt upgrade to keep them synced.  but now the sata drive is stuck on 6.2.0-37 while the nvme has 6.2.0-37&-39 6.5.0-14.
several attempts to upgrade using  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade have failed and attempt to apt install kernel have failed.  if more info is needed please ask.

anyone know of a fix?

Thanks Jim

Oh this is not a dual-boot with window

Answer (score -1):

apparently nvidia:390 is not able to compile on 6.5.0-14
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/linux-new-kernel-6-5-0-14-ubuntu-22-04-can-not-compile-nvidia-display-card-driver/278553